# Hide add button

Tags: swift

I am trying to have a button, so the user can hide the add banner if they want to, this works but when the add banner is not displaying I want the button to also be hidden. So I added the following code, but as soon as I did so, the button stopped working. Any ideas as to why?
thank you!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Banner.hidden == false{

            hideAdd.hidden = false

        } else {
            hideAdd.hidden = true
        }
```

The following is the code I used to hide the banner

```
@IBAction func HideAddButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    Banner.hidden = true

}
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit more on how the button stopped working? In which aspect did it stop working?

Comment: It used to hide the add banner, and when I put this code in , it didn't do that anymore, let me know if you need to know more @Flying_Banana

Comment: Doesn't seem like anything weird should happen - are you sure it works as soon as you take out this code? Perhaps also post your code at how you hide the banner?

Comment: @Flying_Banana Yes I am sure, I tested it several times to check, I also added the code I used to hide the banner in the question.

Comment: Can you add a print to see if the hideAddButton function is called?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to hide and unhide objects on a MainStoryboard is to change the alpha to 0 in the attributes inspector. Then when you want it to appear you can just change the alpha in your code to 1 when you want it to appear in ViewController.swift. Or Vice Versa.